# How to best use Solr parser syntax in a specific business requirement

Tags: parsing, search, solr

Just starting to learn Solr for a project at work and was wondering on how to go about this issue.  Our application allows a user to search based on a business name.  The business name is comprised of 3 different categories ( English, French and Combined Name ).  Based on a single query entered by the user, how would one go about using Solr to provide the most relevant search results?  I have looked into fuzzy and proximity searches which seem reasonable enough.  Although fuzzy search only applies to a single term, which makes me believe that I would need to split the query into single terms and apply fuzzy search to each and merge the results if I were to use it ?  My question is how to best approach the problem ?  Thanks!

Comment: "Most relevant search results" is very application specific - you can use `qf` to search in multiple fields from a single query. You'll have to be more specific and possibly show what you want compared to what you're getting. But if you want to use fuzziness (edit distance), you'll have to supply the distance for each term in the query yourself. There's an older patch to allow the `qf` definition to have fuzziness embedded, but I'm not sure if it still works with 6.1: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-629

Answer (score 0):

To provide relevancy to your documents , you need to have a combination of proper boosting queries and your priorities as what relevance means to your use case . If  Regex based search is included in use case you may go for NGrams , if exact search is what you seeking for , boosting is important . You can use parameters like phrase slope , mm, and other edismax parameters to your advantage . You  may use a combination of title and text content search, with a good combination of boosts . Also , Solr allows you to pass your query in parenthesis, that functions like an SQL IN query , that further boosts relevancy in your documents by sticking to keywords only mentioned in the query . And , at last , if all these doesn't suffice, you may use custom function queries to meet your needs . While doing all this, just keep in mind the Analyzers in schema.xml file are just right and serve the purpose to execute above mentioned queries .

Answer (score 0):

You can go as far down this rabbit-hole as you have time for wrt Business Name search.  (Fuzzy, sound-alike, language-specific analysis, weird compounded-terms used as a domain name (eg: getting "EZBake" to match "easy bake", or "1-to-1" to match "one to one" is non-trivial)

Since this sounds like a pre-existing application, I typically look to query logs (when available) to sample the frequency of different types of mismatches (dig out the zero-result search terms and start manually categorizing the high-level issues behind the more common mismatches).

That will provide you with a backlog of "matching use cases to research how to implement" (in the order of maximal benefit, as determined by your sample).

Then you're ready to start burning them down, and asking much more specific questions about how to get Solr to jump through your domain-specific hoops.